# Git workflow for dev and production

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge, server

I'm trying to figure out a workflow for a git.

I have one codebase, with two branches (development and production). This is for a web app, so *development* has config files, task runners etc. and *production* is just the files I need on my server (e.g. minified scripts and stylesheets).

What I would like to do is be able to work locally (so I will be in the development branch), and when I am ready to push to my server, I would run my build tasks necessary and push to the *production* branch. This way both branches stay in sync with each other, bar production not having some unnecessary files that development has.

Attempting to do this with *git merge*, but there will always be a conflict as production tracks files development does not. Is it possible, without manually listing all the files, to merge/sync a branch with another, whilst retaining both branches and git not looking for files which do not already exist within the branch I am attempting to merge to?

I hope this makes sense, thanks

Comment: It sounds like you're overcomplicating your usage of branches. I would recommend sticking to a single master branch and using an environment variable to keep track of if it's running in development or production. You can conditionally load config files, disable/enable task runners, and start different files depending on the variable.

Comment: @Nick McCurdy I've looked into this further and I have to agree, thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you wan to merge development branch into production branch and auto solving the merge conflicts files. You can use

```
git checkout production
git merge development -X theirs
```

So after finishing merge, your production branch will have the latest config files, task runners etc as the development branch has.